# How can I move a background image pattern around?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked around for this but I couldn't find an answer, and I don't have a clue how I would do it. What I am looking for is a JavaScript or jQuery script that will "move" a background image to the right in a div container, so that the pattern will have an "animated" effect.

How would it be possible to do this? I apologize if I have not explained the question in enough detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS [`background-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-position) property to set the position of the background.

Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/emavur) that moves the background one pixel to the right every quarter second, resetting when it reaches 100 pixels.

HTML:

```
<div id="theDiv">This is the div</div>
```

CSS:

```
#theDiv {
    background-image: url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7b13c109d50df67d5f7d0b1d901d7fb7?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var pos = 0;
  move();

  function move() {
    ++pos;
    if (pos > 100) {
      pos = 0;
    }
    $("#theDiv").css("background-position", pos + "px");
    setTimeout(move, 250);
  }

});
```

Comment: This works fine, however while the background is moving, the where it used to be is just a big blank space. Is it somehow possible to make it so when part of the background that has finished scrolling off the right it returns back to the left?

Comment: `background-repeat: repeat-x;`

Comment: @Alex: See Sim's remark; [details](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-repeat).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `jQuery.animate` on a background position, because:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value.

And `background-position` is not a single numeric value property.

Thus, your best bet is to not use a background image in this case directly. You could re-do your layout so that the image is actually an absolutely positioned `<div>` (the size of your background image) within another fixed-size `<div>` container (`position: relative; overflow: hidden;`). And then to make it "move" -- animate CSS `left` property on your absolutely positioned `<div>`.